# How to switch layouts in a single Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, onlongclicklistener

I have two layouts that I want to be able to switch between using a longclicklistener in a fragment. The layouts are identical except for colors and backgrounds, and the id's for views in each of their xmls are the same, so that code can be run using both layouts the same way. I'm wondering what code to use to change these layouts. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Even want data to flow between them?

Comment: Yeah. They two layouts are just an aesthetic change, their behavior should be exactly the same.

Comment: If everything is the same you can just change the colors programmatically instead of using different layouts..

Answer (score 0):

If the two layout are the same except the background colours , you can just change the ui components background colours at runtime programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can used ViewSwitcher view
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html